# Updating 14.04 to 16.04. Can I do it without impacting LVM?

Tags: 14.04, updates, 16.04, lvm

I'm not a Linux whiz by any means.  A few years ago I struggled through learning how to set up my 3 drives as one large drive using LVM.  I'd just as soon not have to re-learn or risk the data that's on them.  Only data files are there.  All OS files are on a different drive.

If I install 16.04 onto that other drive... what am I going to have to do to get the LVM back?  Anything I need to do prior to prep for it?

I'm not really sure I should be upgrading... I just see that support ends in August for 14.04.

Comment: According to the [Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_or_15.10) the upgrade version will be activated in version 16.04.1 which will be around July of this year.  There should not be any hurry to upgrade since the 14.04 support ends in [Late 2019](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS).  Also, 16.04 defaults to LVM setup.

Comment: Oh!  OK, thank you.  I saw https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases suggesting (at least how I understood it) an August 2016 support end.

Comment: Yeah, that can be confusing, but only the HWE ends in August of this year.   The HWE is HardWare Enablement.   [This might help](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) give you a little more information on the HWE.  The actual LTS support goes till 2019.

Answer (score 0):

If your "LVM drive" contains your $HOME accounts and the OS, /var, /tmp... are on another drive, LVM or not, then you should be okay. Make sure that you select the correct drive when asked during the install where the OS will go.  If the OS and $HOME are on the same drive, I can't comment on your success with this configuration.

Last week I did this dance, upgrading from Ubuntu 14 to 16. I have two LVM Volume Groups. One dedicated to my important data being $HOME and /photographs. The other to the OS, /var, /tmp and swap.

After the upgrade I did have to update /etc/fstab to include my $HOME [mount(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) information. Moved the /home/_install_created_user_ account out of the way and create a new /home mount point for my LVM Volume. Then just addgroup(8) and adduser(8) and I was off the the races.

As always having a solid backup of your critical data ($HOME, photographs, movies, music...) is critical. [rsync(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) and external hard drives are your friends.

I believe you should be able to test this out via VirtualBox. Create a VM running Ubuntu 14.04, create some extra drives to make two or more LVM Volumes. rsync your $HOME account to the /home LVM. Login check it all out and make any corrections. Then upgrade to 16.04.

Lastly if your machine has a NVIDIA graphics card or you plan on running VirtualBox under Ubuntu 16 then TURN OFF the BIOS setting for UEFI.  If your machine is dual boot this may make windoz unhappy, but who cares about windoz when you have Linux!  I don't.

Comment: lol. You can just disable secure boot, UEFI works just fine. Don't give bad advice.

Comment: @JoakimKoed: Your comment doesn't seem particularly helpful. Maybe _you_ should provide an answer of your own.